# unable to run schema_change job in tigergraph

Tags: graph-databases, tigergraph

I am able to create local schema change job for an existing graphDB.
When i try to run the job, i get the error

Current graph version 0, Fail to run job, nothing changed.

[image: 1]

Comment: Were you able to CREATE SCHEMA CHANGE JOB without issues before running the RUN SCHEMA CHANGE JOB?

Docs: https://docs.tigergraph.com/gsql-ref/current/ddl-and-loading/modifying-a-graph-schema#_create_schema_change_job_local

Comment: @Herk Yes, No issues in creating GRAPH and SCHEMA_CHANGE job for graph